# Azure Function V2 - Error :The connection with the server was terminated abnormally

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have developed the function app v2 with Service bus trigger - https://oneprofilesyncappeus.azurewebsites.net and deployed to the production three weeks back and seeing this issue being logged from 22nd Dec in the App insight. As per the error message and stack trace I see this error happening in the Azure function module well before message is received in my programming module.

Error Message:

```
Error while copying content to a stream. The write operation failed, see inner exception. 
Error 12030 calling WinHttpWriteData, 'The connection with the server was terminated abnormally'.
```

Stack Trace

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent+d__47.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler+d__131.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler+d__105.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler+d__2.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
Inner exception System.IO.IOException handled at System.Net.Http.HttpContent+d__47.MoveNext:
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent+d__47.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
Inner exception System.Net.Http.WinHttpException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
```

There two instance of function deployed in West US and East US and i see this exception being occurred only in East US although i don't see any CPU spike or configuration change between these two app service.

Comment: Did you try restarting the app service ? is the error happening repeatedly ?

Comment: @HariHaran: I have restarted the app service too. It is not happening repeatedly but happens on once or twice in a day  and I see hundreds of errors logged at that specified time which is happening only in the East US region.

Comment: So the problem is only with East US region ?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: Then try chaning the region and you should report this bug to MSFT

Comment: Thanks, would try it and would create the ticket for the same.

Comment: @PrabhuSomasundaram for the same what?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share the learning that we had with our func app crashing out frequently in production due to high CPU utilization with the exception **"The connection with the server was terminated abnormally"**

Below are the observations that we had:

1. CPU utilization gradually increases till it reaches the 100% and application restarts and sometimes becomes unresponsive too.
2. Increasing the instance didn’t helped.
3. Number of thread count was high during the time of application crash.
4. Number of database connections and memory utilization was within control.
5. Few of the application insight logging was missed.

After we engaged the azure support team and analyzing the dump file, we found that root cause was the way the logger was initialized in our function app.
Please refer this https://evandontje.com/2018/10/09/high-thread-count-in-azure-functions/ which clearly states the reason for this issue and refactored code to resolve the same.